# Enable one specific date in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker on my website, and I have disabled every first and second day (monday and tuesday) of the week. Also I have an array of days which are disabled (this is working). Now I would like to also enable 24-12-2018, but I am stuck here.

My code:

```
var vakantie = ["25-12-2018", "26-12-2018", "27-12-2018", "28-12-2018", "29-12-2018", "30-12-2018", "31-12-2018"];

function nietbeschikbaar(dt) {
    var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dt);
    return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 ? false : true && vakantie.indexOf(datestring) == -1];
};

jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker(jQuery.datepicker.regional["nl"]);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "changeMonth", true);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "minDate", +1);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "firstDay", 1);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "yearRange", "-0:+70");
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", nietbeschikbaar);
```

I also managed to get this code working to only enable the 24th of december, which I would like to have enabled:

```
var enableDays = ["24-12-2018"];

function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date)
    if ($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
        return [true];
    }
    return [false];
}

jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", enableAllTheseDays);
```

I would like to combine these functions if this is possible. So the requirements:

- Every 1st and 2nd day of the week **disabled**
- The 'vakantie' array **disabled**
- 24-12-2018 (24th of december) **enabled**

Comment: Hi charlietfl, 24th of december is a monday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var vakantie = ["25-12-2018", "26-12-2018", "27-12-2018", "28-12-2018", "29-12-2018", "30-12-2018", "31-12-2018"];
var enableDays = ["24-12-2018"];


$("#datepicker").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
var datestring = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dt);
    if($.inArray(datestring, enableDays) != -1) {
     return [true];
         }
    else{
     return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 ? false : true && vakantie.indexOf(datestring) == -1 ];
         }

   
    }});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="datepicker" id="datepicker"></p>

 
 
</body>
```

Try this..

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
     var datestring = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dt);
     if($.inArray(datestring, enableDays) != -1) {
        return [true];
     }
     else{
      return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 ? false : true && vakantie.indexOf(datestring) == -1 ];
     }


}});
```

Comment: YES! it is working! thank you very much, I really really needed this!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following condition inside your `beforeShowDay` function. It basically creates an exception for specified dates:

```
var override = ["24-12-2018"];
// ...
var available = (dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 || vakantie.indexOf(datestring) >= 0) && (override.indexOf(datestring) === -1)
    ? false
    : true;
return [available];
```

```js
var vakantie = ["25-12-2018", "26-12-2018", "27-12-2018", "28-12-2018", "29-12-2018", "30-12-2018", "31-12-2018"];
var override = ["24-12-2018"];

function nietbeschikbaar(dt) {
  var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dt);
  var available = (dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 || vakantie.indexOf(datestring) >= 0) && (override.indexOf(datestring) === -1)
  ? false 
  : true;
  return [available];
}

jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker(jQuery.datepicker.regional["nl"]);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "changeMonth", true);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "changeYear", true);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "minDate", +1);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "firstDay", 1);
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "yearRange", "-0:+70");
jQuery("#cfgen-element-7-6").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", nietbeschikbaar);
```

```css
@import url("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Navigate to December 2018</p>
<p><input id="cfgen-element-7-6"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I couldn't get this working. The answer from Sooriya worked for me.