# Enable and disable dates jquery using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker. I have set an array of dates which should be disabled, this is working fine:

```
    var vakantie = ["25-12-2018", "26-12-2018", "27-12-2018", "28-12-2018", "29-12-2018", "30-12-2018", "31-12-2018"];

function nietBeschikbaar(dt){

    var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dt);
    return [dt.getDay() == 1 || dt.getDay() == 2 ? false : true && vakantie.indexOf(datestring) == -1 ];

};

jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", nietBeschikbaar);
```

Now I would also want one date to be enabled (every monday and tuesday is also disabled, but this date is on a monday). With this code I can disable everything except this one date:

```
    var enableDays = ["24-12-2018"];

function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd-mm-yy', date)
    if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
        return [true];
    }
    return [false];
}

jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", enableAllTheseDays);
```

But now I would like to combine these two scripts, so I would like to disable the 'vakantie' array, and also enable the 'enableDays' array. I can't get them working togheter, could anyone help me out?

Comment: You already asked this question. If you want to add more information, please edit the original.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I now editted the original.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, test it please:

```
function enableAllTheseDays() {
    var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd-mm-yy', date);
    var evaluateArray = vakantie.some(function(item){
       return item == sdate;   
    });
    var arrayWithResult = [];
    arrayWithResult.push(evaluateArray);
    return arrayWithResult;
}
```

Just make sure that sdate is a string variable in this format:

"dd-mm-yy"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Hey @Mxkert, just updated, did some testing here, it seems to be working now, but just be sure about the format of the variable sdate!

Comment: Hi @TiagoM, I still could not get this one working, maybe it is a fault from my side. Anyway thank you for thinking with me. Also as Rory mentioned, this post was a duplicate, on the other post I got an answer that worked for me. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434238/enable-one-specific-date-in-jquery-datepicker/53443319#53443319).